# Unnesting multiple columns with a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. I have a table like so -

```
Org1        Org2  Org3  Org4  Ind1  Ind2      
15483663a   12d               321   154833a     
15483663a                     123a  16091a      
15483663a                     341a  13061a      
15483663B                     232a  17503918a
```

This is the result I am looking for -

```
Org       Count
15483663a 6 (First 3 records in Ind1 and Ind2)
12d       2 (First record in Ind1 and Ind2)
```

I am expecting `6` for `15483663a` because of these records in `Ind1` and `Ind2` - `321, 154833a, 123a, 16091a, 341a, 13061a`

Comment: Explain the logic. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: why 2nd row in your result is from Org2-12d and not 15483663B ??

Comment: Because I need results of both `Org1` and `Org2`. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT Org1, COUNT(Ind1), + COUNT(Ind2)
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY Org1
```

You may consider `COUNT(DISTINCT Ind1)` if don't want count duplicates